# Proper property loop of objects

Tags: javascript

OK. So until now I have *"gotten away"* with using things like this:

```
function foo(arg) {
    // Default values:
    var opt = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }, 
        key;
    for (key in opt)
        if (opt.hasOwnProperty(key) && arg.hasOwnProperty(key))
           opt[key] = arg[key];
}
```

Now, I'm more and more bashed for using `hasOwnProperty` as it could have been overridden by some custom property.

If we are going to use *`keys()`*, *`forEach()`* etc. instead what is the proper way of doing things like the above? Something like this?

```
function bar(arg) {
    // Default values:
    var opt = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }, 
        keys = Object.keys(arg);
    Object.keys(opt).forEach(function(key) {
        if (keys.indexOf(key) !== -1)
            opt[key] = arg[key];
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are concerning `hasOwnProperty` has been overridden, then you could do:

```
Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(arg, key)
```

So your original code could be:

```
function foo(arg) {
    var opt = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 },
        check = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty,
        key;
    for (key in opt) {
        if (check.call(opt, key) && check.call(arg, key)) {
            opt[key] = arg[key];
        }
    }
    return opt;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that is a good option. But, some people even say I should not use the *hasOwnProperty* directly on e.g. the internal *opt* like above. I can't really understand that as: *where could that ever be overridden* when it is in a short closed scope like that.

Comment: @user3342816 `Object.prototype.foo = 1` will affect `opt`.

Comment: Ah, OK. Thanks. PS: Typo on third line `;` and not `,` at end of line.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with your original code — except for the shocking lack of `{` and `}`! ;-)

If you feel for some reason you need to use `Object.keys` and `forEach` instead, you don't need to get the keys of `arg`, just `opt`. This would be the equivalent of your first code block, using `Object.keys` and `forEach`.

```
function bar(arg) {
    // Default values:
    var opt = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };
    Object.keys(opt).forEach(function(key) {
        if (arg.hasOwnProperty(key))
            opt[key] = arg[key];
    });
}
```

But again, there's no reason to change it, your original code is fine.

> Now, I'm more and more bashed for using hasOwnProperty as it could have been overridden by some custom property.

If someone overrides `hasOwnProperty`, then in theory they have a good reason for doing so. I wouldn't worry about it except in some special situations. But if you want to avoid that concern, you can do this:

```
var hop = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty;
function foo(arg) {
    // Default values:
    var opt = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }, 
        key;
    for (key in opt)
        if (hop.call(opt, key) && hop.call(arg, key))
           opt[key] = arg[key];
}
```

Then your only concern is whether somebody replaced `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty`; if they did, and their replacement didn't work properly, your loop would probably be the least of their concerns.

Comment: Yes, I have a habit of not using `{}` when there is only one operation on next line. Perhaps bad. If I need to change it or not is one point where I'm a bit unsure. Have gotten feedback on similar code as the above with *Newer use hasOwnProperty* use [es5-shim](https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim) keys etc. I can't say I'm comfortable arguing either way. Other then including the shim for smaller projects seems a bit overkill.

Comment: @user3342816: *"Yes, I have a habit of not using {} when there is only one operation on next line."* Just about every style guide you'll find requires always using braces, because study after study shows doing so consistently reduces bugs (both the first time code is written, and when it's edited). *"Have gotten feedback on similar code as the above with Newer use hasOwnProperty use es5-shim keys"* Frankly, I'd call that very suspect advice. :-)